# Updating macOS resets Widgets every release

Tags: macos, mac, widgets

How can I fix this issue? Usually, I have weather, clock, and calendar in the Widgets, but there are only weather and clock widgets after updating, macOS Big Sur.

Comment: What version of macOS? What does, "but there are weather and clock after updating." mean? Was that a typo or something else?

Comment: I use Big Surr.